# Make Overlay Scroll Bars always on?

Tags: scrolling

I think the overlay scrollbars that come up in menus and the Nautilus file manager work really well, especially with my touchscreen (it doesn't allow gestures, rather bittersweet). I've found ways to disable them, but is there a way to do the opposite? Can I make them so that they always appear, regardless of my mouse position?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make your scrollbar always visible, write this in terminal:

```
sudo gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

`gsettings` is to get/set system settings, and you're setting the `scrollbar-mode` to normal, you need `sudo` because you're making changes to the system.

To reset to default behaviour:

```
sudo gsettings reset com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode
```

You can also achieve the same via Unity tweak tool. If you do not have it installed you can install it:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Then under System menu go to Scrolling > Under Scrollbars, change from overlay to Legacy.

There's no current way to set the 'overlay' to always appear. Setting your scrollbars to `normal` turns the 'hover to show' off.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question: I WANT them on. I want to make them so that they appear on screen without my mouse being near the scroll bar. Is that possible?

Comment: Overlay bars mean that they will show only when your mouse is over the border. Disabling them will make the scroll always visible. Did you executed the first command that I gave you? Execute it in terminal and see :)

Comment: No, I want the overlay to always be on. I don't want them gone. I want that little overlay square thingy to always be on no matter where my mouse is. So, I can just touch them with my touch screen without having to hover over them first.

Comment: Ok, mate did you executed the command that I proposed to you?

Comment: No, because the top one DISABLES overlays, and the next one just resets them to default. How will that help me? I will have effectively command-prompted my way in a circle. And I have Unity Tweak Tool installed already, I see no option for having the overlays always on. I would add a picture of what I want but for some reason this forum won't let me (not a very effective forum, is it?)

Comment: You can upload it to external place and then just post link to the image, like [here](https://imageshack.us/)

Comment: I want the overlays always on, like so [link](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img538/7660/Jl3IsU.jpg) but I don't want to have to move my mouse to the scroll bars to see the overlays. I just want them to be on all the time.

Comment: OK the command that I have proposed to you makes them always visible like [this](http://www.jijokjose.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/old-scrollbars.png)

Comment: Cool. That isn't what I want. I want the squares.

Comment: Ah now understand you. Unfortunately I do not know if this is possible. I know that you can turn them on and off, but not to make them always visible.

Comment: Okay. Thank you, anyway! I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the scrollbar overlay - which means they are always on. Add this to your ~/.profile:

```
export GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you try to uninstall the "overlay-scrollbar" package? It worked for me on xenial...

```
sudo apt-get purge overlay-scrollbar
```